# Getting error while Authenticating online TFS from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to connect online TFS using WCF service but it is throwing me exception "TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://abdul-r.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TestTFS.".

Below is my sample code

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(
            "*MyEmail*",
           "*MyPassword*");
        BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);

        TfsClientCredentials credential = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
        credential.AllowInteractive = false;

        string TFSServerPath = "https://abdul-r.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TestTFS";

        using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs1 = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFSServerPath), credential))
        {

            tfs1.EnsureAuthenticated();
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding the domain to the username? so that the username will be YourDomain\abdul-r@hcl.com

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your quick concern.
As this is windows live id and TFS is online so no need of Domain to provide. I checked, NetworkCredential is having overloaded method to accept without domain. Any other ideas appreciated.